# date('H:i',$ans) returns wrong value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to calculate a time difference in php script. There are in time and out time values. I wrote following code to get the difference. But it always returns correct answer + 1 value.

```
$inTime = '08:30:00';
$outTime = '17:48:00';
$difference = date('H:i',((strtotime($outTime) - strtotime($inTime))));
echo $difference;
```

The out put is printed as 10:18. But the output should be 09:18. I use Codeigniter framwork. I run this code with online php tester (http://phptester.net/) and it returns the correct value.

Comment: are you sure strtotime allows "H:i:s" format ?

Comment: Sure..The code is run correctly in http://phptester.net/

Comment: and phptester.net gives the right result... so it may be an environnement problem... what is your php version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function datediff( $date1, $date2 )
{
    $diff = abs( strtotime( $date1 ) - strtotime( $date2 ) );

    return sprintf
    (
        "%d Days, %d Hours, %d Mins, %d Seconds",
        intval( $diff / 86400 ),
        intval( ( $diff % 86400 ) / 3600),
        intval( ( $diff / 60 ) % 60 ),
        intval( $diff % 60 )
    );
}

$inTime = '08:30:00';
$outTime = '17:48:00';
print datediff( $inTime, $outTime ) . "\n";
```

**Online Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/564133)**

**For only Minutes:**

```
function datediff( $date1, $date2 )
{
    $diff = abs( strtotime( $date1 ) - strtotime( $date2 ) );

    return sprintf
    (
        "%d Mins",
        intval(((( $diff % 86400 ) / 3600) * 60))
    );
}

$inTime = '08:30:00';
$outTime = '17:48:00';

print datediff( $inTime, $outTime ) . "\n";
```

**Output**

```
558 Mins
```

**Online Demo:  [Click Here](https://eval.in/564231)**

Comment: I don't know..I'm not doing that. But I correct it. So how do I get entire difference in minutes??

Answer (score 1):

check out this method...

```
<?php

$time1    = new DateTime('08:30:00');
$time2   = new DateTime('17:48:00');
$interval = $time2->diff($time1);
echo "Time Difference : ".$interval->format('%H hours %i minutes %s seconds');

?>
```

This will output :

```
Time Difference : 09 hours 18 minutes 0 seconds
```

Comment: @Random sorry, i did it by mistake.. now I've edited the answer with new method...

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can do this, personally I would use PHP's built in time difference functions.

```
$inTime = date_create('08:30:0');
$outTime = date_create('17:48:00');
$difference = date_diff($inTime, $outTime);
echo $difference->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

outputs:

> 09:18:00

[example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0dcc2e13d9e2f9ffde0cd59410cdcf4fefce02f)